# Как восстановить PackageReference при сборке проекта с разными конфигурациями

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, msbuild

Создал проект в VS 2019 (Библиотека классов Net Framework).
Задумка в следующем - мне нужно использовать один проект, но собирать разные dll в зависимости от конфигураций. Это нужно для написания плагинов под разные версии Revit.

В проекте создал конфигурации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в csproj файле настроил конфигурации на разные версии Net Framework. Пример:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'R2020|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\R2020\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;R2020</DefineConstants>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

И подключил разные NuGet пакеты, используя Choose/When:

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='R2020' ">
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="ModPlus.Revit.API.2020">
          <Version>1.0.0</Version>
          <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
      </ItemGroup>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblyName>$(AssemblyName)_2020</AssemblyName>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```

И вот все почти хорошо, но: когда я меняю в Visual Studio конфигурацию, то NuGet-пакеты не загружаются. Чтобы при этом собрать проект нужно сначала нажать ПКМ на решении и выбрать пункт "Восстановить пакеты NuGet"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот проблема в том, что для построения проекта под каждую конфигурацию нужно делать восстановление пакетов.

Вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы пакеты восстанавливались автоматически перед сборкой, чтобы иметь возможность собирать все конфигурации пакетной сборкой?

Comment: Если разница конфигураций только в используемой версии `.NET Framework'а` - проекты в `.NET SDK` style позволяют указывать список `TFM`, например: `<TargetFramework>net460;net461</TargetFramework>`.

Comment: [Target frameworks in SDK-style projects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks). Там же и пример с PackageReference.